# font color android html

Tags: android, html, css

I am making a note application and want the user to be able to edit in rich text.

The user writes the note, then it gets converted into html and saved into a database.

This way when it is retrieved from the database, it does not lose its rich text.

Yet I am having a problem, if the user adds a color to their text and saves the note it converts it to html like this

```
"<p><font color=#0000ff>user text</font></p>"
```

when retrieved from the database no text color shows up. this is because android saves the html wrong. In order for android to get color from html the letters need to be capitalized like this

```
"<p><font color=#0000FF>user text</font></p>"
```

This confuses me because if android can only read it in caos why doesn't it convert it in that way.

**How do I get it so when this code runs**

```
    //--save to string--//
    Editable e = noteContent.getText();
    String s2 = Html.toHtml(e);

    Spanned s3 = Html.fromHtml(s2);
    classes.setText(s3);
```

**to save the text color to the caps. so when it is retrieved form the database the text color shows up.**

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your RGB value is CAPITALIZED. 
Try to use:

```
Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<font color='#145A14'>text</font>]]>");
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I understand the value needs to be capitalized. The problem is the text that is being converted to html is dynamic. in other words the user types down there notes with the font color changes hits save and this code runs  Editable e = noteContent.getText();
 String s2 = Html.toHtml(e); android makes the html conversion lowercase not uppercase. when the text is set toHtml